# Sending CEC commands via command line over HDMI

Tags: raspberry-pi, television, hdmi

My master plan is to be able to send CEC commands from my raspberry pi to do things such as turn on/off the tv as well as other devices connected to the TV. Then I will be adding voice recognition to send these commands...that's for another day. I have read up on CEC but from what I've gathered it seems like you can't send CEC commands directly through the command line without the CEC usb adapter? I have installed the cec-client and libCEC library on my pi but when I run cec-client -l it shows no devices.

My question is, how can I send CEC commands via the command line to my tv from the pi without the adapter? Am I missing some basic element about CEC?

**UPDATE**

In addition to the posts below here is a link that asked in the PI portion of stackoverflow which has some more CEC commands that I have put within my .bashrc to turn the tv on/off and change the input

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5345/raspmbc-send-cec-commands-without-cec-adapter

Comment: I dont know if it is of use for you but maybe it is a starting point. [libCEC](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent versions of libcec will recognize the Raspberry Pi hardware as a CEC adapter.
To send control commands through the command line, basically:

```
echo "on 0" | cec-client -s
```

will power on device 0 (ie your TV)
Check out cec-client interactive shell for more complex commands

Comment: Currently cec-client unregisters all active CEC listeners. After you perform this command Kodi, losses connection to HDMI network.

Answer (score 7):

You can pipe commands to the cec-client binary

```
echo "on 0"      | cec-client -s # turn on the television
echo "standby 0" | cec-client -s # turn it off (standby)
```

For completeness, these are some other things that you can do

List connected devices

```
tv# cec-client -l
libCEC version: 3.1.0, git revision: libcec-3.1.0+5-6d68d21, compiled on Fri  8 Apr 15:44:58 UTC 2016 by nacho@tv on Linux 4.1.19-v7+ (armv7l), features: P8_USB, DRM, P8_detect, randr, RPi
Found devices: 1

device:              1
com port:            RPI
vendor id:           2708
product id:          1001
firmware version:    1
type:                Raspberry Pi
```

Check all available CEC commands

```
tv# echo h | cec-client -s -d 1
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...

================================================================================
Available commands:

[tx] {bytes}              transfer bytes over the CEC line.
[txn] {bytes}             transfer bytes but don't wait for transmission ACK.
[on] {address}            power on the device with the given logical address.
[standby] {address}       put the device with the given address in standby mode.
[la] {logical address}    change the logical address of the CEC adapter.
[p] {device} {port}       change the HDMI port number of the CEC adapter.
[pa] {physical address}   change the physical address of the CEC adapter.
[as]                      make the CEC adapter the active source.
[is]                      mark the CEC adapter as inactive source.
[osd] {addr} {string}     set OSD message on the specified device.
[ver] {addr}              get the CEC version of the specified device.
[ven] {addr}              get the vendor ID of the specified device.
[lang] {addr}             get the menu language of the specified device.
[pow] {addr}              get the power status of the specified device.
[name] {addr}             get the OSD name of the specified device.
[poll] {addr}             poll the specified device.
[lad]                     lists active devices on the bus
[ad] {addr}               checks whether the specified device is active.
[at] {type}               checks whether the specified device type is active.
[sp] {addr}               makes the specified physical address active.
[spl] {addr}              makes the specified logical address active.
[volup]                   send a volume up command to the amp if present
[voldown]                 send a volume down command to the amp if present
[mute]                    send a mute/unmute command to the amp if present
[self]                    show the list of addresses controlled by libCEC
[scan]                    scan the CEC bus and display device info
[mon] {1|0}               enable or disable CEC bus monitoring.
[log] {1 - 31}            change the log level. see cectypes.h for values.
[ping]                    send a ping command to the CEC adapter.
[bl]                      to let the adapter enter the bootloader, to upgrade
                          the flash rom.
[r]                       reconnect to the CEC adapter.
[h] or [help]             show this help.
[q] or [quit]             to quit the CEC test client and switch off all
                          connected CEC devices.
================================================================================
```

Extracted from

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/02/control-your-raspberry-pi-with-your-tv-remote/